# Can't Scroll up with dynamic absolute DIV

Tags: html, css

I made a div with several divs inside, that are opened with different buttons.

The div is centered, with absolute position, in the middle of the page.

The problem that I have is, that when I open this different divs, and the main DIV starts to go up, it disappear from the body itself, and i cannot see it and neither scroll up.

There is a way to stick it to the middle, or just limit the top of the body?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ecf0f1;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  background: #e74c3c;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 39px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 39px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 39px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not specifying a height for your container, it will continue to grow - eventually starting off the top of the page. If you want it to be no more than a maximum height, you need to specify that in the CSS.

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: #e74c3c;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 39px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 39px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 39px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use rather flexbox than position absolute on it. For browser support, you can visit [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Assuming you won't place any content outside the `.container`, you may 
change `body` css to be like in code below.

If not , you can wrap the `.container` with another `div` with 100% height and width, and apply the code to new `div`

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* To center align horizontally*/
  align-items: center; /* To center align vertically*/
}
```

and remove `position: absolute`, `top: 50%`, `left: 50%`, and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` from your `.container`.

Comment: It works centering my div, but it has the same behaviour than before.

Goes up till I cannot scroll to see the top of. :(

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention that you also need to specify a fixed height for your `.container` and `overflow-y: scroll`, so the divs won't push the `.container` up.